# Three ways to assgin values to an array in z3

Tags: z3, smt

As far as I know, there are three ways to assgin values to an array in z3.

1. use `assert` to assgin values to some of the cells:

```
(declare-const a1 (Array Int Int))
(declare-const a2 (Array Int Int))

(assert (= 1 (select a1 0)))
(assert (= 2 (select a2 0)))
```

z3 returns `unsat` when the constraint `(assert (= a1 a2))` is added.

2. use `as const` to initialize the array first and then assgin values to specific cells:

```
(declare-const a3 (Array Int Int))
(assert
    (=
        (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 64) 0 3)
        a3
    )
)
(declare-const a4 (Array Int Int))
(assert
    (=
        (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 64) 0 4)
        a4
    )
)
```

Add `(assert (= a3 a4))` and we obtain `unsat` again.

3. define the array via a function:

```
(define-const a5 (Array Int Int)
    (lambda ((i Int))
    (ite (= i 0) 5 64)))
(define-const a6 (Array Int Int)
    (lambda ((i Int))
    (ite (= i 0) 6 64)))
```

But if we add `(assert (= a5 a6))`, z3 returns `sat`. Why?

By the way, is there any (better) way to assign values to an array in z3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Check out this [issue](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2221#issuecomment-480861134).